# JavaScript equivalent for jQuery's $.ajax function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have the following jQuery code:

```
dataString = 'test'; // array?
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "tokenize.php",
    data: {
        data: dataString
    }, 
    cache: false,
    success: function (data) {
        returnedvalue = data;
        console.log(data); //alert isn't for debugging
    }
});
```

This jQuery code is working fine, but I want a plain JavaScript version of this code which I'm not able to figure out how to do. I made up this code with help from Stack Overflow only.

I have seen that this can be done using `XMLHttpRequest`:

```
var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "tokenize.php";
var params = "lorem=ipsum&name=binny"; // What will be done here in my case?
http.open("POST", url, true);

//Send the proper header information along with the request
http.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
http.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");

// Call a function when the state changes.
http.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
        alert(http.responseText);
    }
}
http.send(params);
```

Comment: Check this demo. http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/tryit.asp?filename=tryajax_first

Comment: Thanks,but my question was different.I have the samples but how shoudl I sent my parameters ? and I need POST

Comment: You're almost always better using a library like jQuery to make AJAX requests, because it abstracts the browser differences away for you. If you're set on using XMLHttpRequest directly, I suggest that you start with the documentation here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest

Answer (score 0):

The format of `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` data is:

```
key=value&key=value&key=value
```

Run each key and value through [`encodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) to deal with characters that have special meaning or that aren't allowed in the encoding.